# in a xcode webview: how to get the name or id of input tag selected?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

Inside an xcode application, I have an webview with a variable number of text input.

There is a method to get to xcode the attribute "name" or "id" when I selected the field?

My problem is that I don't know how to pass the name or id of selected field to xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

```
NSString *string = 
   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('your_id_here');"];
```